# Why does puppeteer show me a DOMEXCEPTION :"Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document"?

Tags: puppeteer, queryselector

i am trying to click on an input (with puppeteer) but, when executing the code an error is thrown, the error is the following:

Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '##login_content > div.loginSection.estudiantes > form > p:nth-child(1) > input' is not a valid selector.

````
       const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#login_content > 
              div.loginSection.estudiantes > form > p:nth-child(1)  > input';

        const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#login_content > 
              div.loginSection.estudiantes > form > p:nth-child(2) > input';

        const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '#login_content > 
              div.loginSection.estudiantes > form > p:nth-child(3) > input';

        await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);```
````

Comment: Do you have a new line in the selector?

Comment: @hardkoded what you exactly mean?

Comment: Do you have `#login_content >` and the rest in a new line, as in the example? if so, could you try removing that new line?

Comment: ok, no. in my code there are no spaces but now everything is working... without fixing anything, it is weird.